# displaying products from database using php

Tags: php

This is a php code for displaying 3 products (from database). It displays products in a raw, but their is a fault  that the first product that should appears in the very next raw is missing.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shopping") or
        die("Please, check your server connection.");
        $query = "SELECT item_code, item_name, description, imagename, price FROM
            products";
        $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysql_error());
        echo "<table border=\"0\">";
        $x = 1;
        echo "<tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if ($x <= 3) {
                $x = $x + 1;
                extract($row);
                echo "<td style=\"padding-right:15px;\">";
                echo "<a href=itemdetails.php?itemcode=$item_code>";
                echo '<img src=' . $imagename . ' style="max-width:220px;max-height:240px;
            width:auto;height:auto;"></img><br/>';
                echo $item_name . '<br/>';
                echo "</a>";
                echo '$' . $price . '<br/>';
                echo "</td>";
            }
            else {
                $x = 1;
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `$x` to zero. `$x=0;`

Complete code:-

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "shopping") or
        die("Please, check your server connection.");
        $query = "SELECT item_code, item_name, description, imagename, price FROM products";
        $results = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
        echo "<table border=\"0\">";
        $x=0;
        echo "<tr>";
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if ($x <= 3)
            {
                $x = $x + 1;
                extract($row);
                echo "<td style=\"padding-right:15px;\">";
                echo "<a href=itemdetails.php?itemcode=$item_code>";
                echo '<img src=' . $imagename . ' style="max-width:220px;max-height:240px; width:auto;height:auto;"></img><br/>';
                echo $item_name .'<br/>';
                echo "</a>";
                echo '$'.$price .'<br/>';
                echo "</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                $x=1;
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need little modification to your code:

```
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            if ($x > 3) {
                  $x = 1;
                  echo "</tr><tr>";
            }

            $x = $x + 1;
            extract($row);
            echo "<td style=\"padding-right:15px;\">";
            echo "<a href=itemdetails.php?itemcode=$item_code>";
            echo '<img src=' . $imagename . ' style="max-width:220px;max-height:240px;
        width:auto;height:auto;"></img><br/>';
            echo $item_name . '<br/>';
            echo "</a>";
            echo '$' . $price . '<br/>';
            echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
    ?>
</body>
```

You can change reset of x according to your needs ... May be reset $x=0. I also added closing tr tag, because otherwise it will remain open although now days browsers will fix that missing tag for you.